# Reversing original array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to reverse this array, and am starting off by making the end half of the array become the first half. Is there a reason why my output is skipping putting 9 into array[0]? I have array[0] = tem[9-0-1] so array[0] = temp[8]? Isnt this true?

```
def sameArray(array)
  temp = array
  for i in array[0]..(((array.length)/2).floor)
      array[i] = temp[array.length - i - 1]
      ##puts array[i]
  end
end

sameArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

# array[0] => array[8]
#array[1] => array[7]
#array[2] => array[6]
#array[3] => array[5]
```

Comment: Because `(9/2).floor = 4`

Comment: One clever and efficient way to reverse an array is to have one index `i` starting at 0, the second `j` starting at the end of the array.  Then, `while (i < j)`, swap `array[i]` with `array[j]` using a temporary `t`.  Then, increment `i` and decrement `j`.  *(The Ruby code is left as an exercise for the reader.)*

Comment: Hmm. How do i fix this then?

Comment: i.e, the floor part

Comment: @MikeRobinson. How can I have two index's? So I need two for loops and a while loop?

Comment: Even if 9/2.floor is = 4. Why isnt the first term showing? thats the 0th spot

Comment: Shravan kindly wrote the Ruby code in his answer to the question.  (*Notice* that the test is `<`, **not** "or equal," `<=`.)  If the list contains an odd number of elements, both cursors run to the middle.  And, as Shravan also points out, "a method is already provided that does this."

Answer (score 3):

There are few issues in your program:

1. You are not really swapping the values from indices `i` and `array.length - i - 1`, hence, array is not getting full reversed
2. Your method does not return the updated array, but instead returns the result of `for` loop which is the range `[1..4]`.
3. Your `for` loop is wrongly using `array[0]` as first value in the range, whereas it should be just `0`.
4. `temp` is not really a copy of `array`, it is just another reference to `array`, and hence, will end up modifying the `array` if any changes are done using `temp`.

Based on above observations, here is an updated method:

```
def sameArray(array)
  temp = array.dup
  for i in 0..(((temp.length)/2).floor)
       temp[i], temp[-i-1] = temp[-i-1], temp[i]
  end
  return temp
end
```

---

Note that `temp.length - i - 1` can be written as `-i-1`, in the same way as `-1` index represents last element of array.

---

By using some idiomatic Ruby, we can rid of temporary variable `temp` and also use `each` in place of `for` loop.  Here is one version of code that can be considered more idiomatic Ruby.

```
def reverse(array)
  array.dup.tap do |a|
    (0..a.length/2).each do |i|
      a[i], a[-i-1] = a[-i-1], a[i]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wand has used what's called [parallel assignment](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch04s05.html) (sometimes called  *multiple assignment*).

Answer (score 2):

```
def sameArray(array)
    len = array.size
    i = 0
    j = len - 1
    while i < j do
       temp = array[i]
       array[i] = array[j]
       array[j] = temp
       i = i+1
       j = j-1
    end
end
```

You can do this in more simple way

```
def sameArray(array)
    array.reverse
end
```

Comment: It's a workaround but not an answer to the OP's question

Comment: @AndrewL. : I know, but it's more simple than, what exactly he is doing.

Comment: True, but the OP asks why his reverse algorithm isn't working, not other ways to solve the problem

Comment: You obviously have not tested this as Ruby does not have methods `++` or `--`.  That earns a downvote. How could there be any upvotes, much less two?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with just one method: [`Array#reverse!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21)

```
def sameArray(array)
  array.reverse!
end

array = [1,2,3,4]
sameArray(array)
array
#=> [4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Why not use [`reverse!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21)?

Comment: @WandMaker: You are right, for some reason it didn't show up in my doc.

Answer (score 0):

According to your way, the code works as following

```
def sameArray(array)
  temp = array
  for i in 0...array.length/2
    t = array[i]
    array[i] = temp[array.length - i - 1]
    temp[array.length - i - 1] = t
    ##puts array[i]
  end

end

sameArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```